# Visual Studio Online, Pathing, C1083 and stdafx.cpp

Tags: c++, msbuild, azure-devops, stdafx.h

So, I'm taking this class.... ***wince***

My day job is pretty technical, but I'm a complete Visual Studio newbie.

I have a Visual Studio Express 2013 project that runs/compiles fine on my local system, but I have to get it to build in Visual Studio Online, so I can share it with the other people in my class.

The very first line of my program is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

When I attempt to build my program in the online build environment, I get an error:

```
Error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\..\..\..\..\path_to\file_on\my_local\computer\Project\stdafx.cpp': No such file or directory
```

The stdafx.cpp and .h files are in the project folder in source control, along with the main.cpp file, as well as showing up earlier in the build log when the project is cloned. But according to the [#include directive docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx) the very first place it looks should be the directory where the main.cpp file lives?

Looking at the XML content of the `.vcxproj` filters files, I'm seeing an entry that looks like this for every file in the project:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Text Include="..\..\..\..\..\path_to\file_on\my_local\computer\Project\ReadMe.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And I'm wondering if that's related, and/or somehow overriding the normal behavior of `#include`. However, I can't find a way to edit those from within Visual Studio (I mean, okay, I could open the file in Notepad++ or something, but that can't be the 'right' way... can it?)

So, is there a (preferably simple) way to tell my VS project to just look in "." for things?

Comment: Don't have a solution, but I do have a cheap hack: recreate the project without pre-compiled headers enabled. The whole `stdafx` issue goes away.

Comment: Either delete and re-add stdafx.cpp to the project (carefully; it has custom build options to construct the precompiled header, so you'd want to copy those first), manually edit the path in the XML (probably simplest) or try creating a new project and re-adding your source.

Comment: Right click on your project and select "Properties" from VS, click "VC++ Directories" under "Configuration Properties", you can set "Include Directories" for include path. The change is reflected in .vcxproj. Check in the changes and then try if the build can be completed successfully.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I ended up editing the vcxproj files manually with Notepad++, removing the long relative paths. Works fine now.

Thanks for the help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue related to space is present between folder name, .sln path should not contain folder name with space, like 'foo foo', it should 'foofoo' or 'foo_foo'